# Classification of Images using Nodes JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am kinda new to NodeJs. I have been trying to make an API which can classify an image and give the resultant in a Json object. The resultant is score prediction using NSFWJS.

My task is when I pass a JSON object with a {key:value} pair where key is "Codes" and the values is a list of Codes which is using to fetch url object, it should parse through every image and give the resultant output.

*** Basic flow of the code ***

Input : A Json object something like this :- *** {'Codes':['Code1','Code2','Code3']} ***

Loop to all the objects from the value :

```
 1. parse through a function to store the image
 2. pas through the model to get the prediction
 3. Stored the resultant in a Json object
```

Return the final Json object

This the code of my implementation :-

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const jpeg = require('jpeg-js')
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const nsfw = require('nsfwjs')
const bodyParser=require("body-parser")
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var request=require('request');
const app = express()
const upload = multer()


app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
let _model
let file_content;
let test_data;
function convertBuffer()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
        {
            try
            {
                file_content=fs.readFileSync('ans1.png');
                resolve(file_content);
            }
            catch
            {
                reject('Null String')
            }           
        })
}


app.post('/nsfw',async(req,res) =>{

    var arrayCodes=req.body.Codes;
    var jsonObj={};
    var i=0;
    var iterator=function(i){
        if(i>arrayCodes.length)
        {
            console.log("Testing",jsonObj);
            res.json(jsonObj);
            return;
        }
    }
    while(i<arrayCodes.length)
    {
        var imgUrl="http://url/to/image"+String(Codes[i])
        //getImageUrl(imgUrl);
        await axios.get(imgUrl)
            .then(response=>{
                var result=response.data;
                var resultJson=result.facets.Media.productImage.url;
                var localPath="ans1.png"
                var fullUrl = resultJson;

                var download=function(uri,filename,callback){
                    request.head(uri,function(err,res,body){
                        // console.log('Content-Type:',res.headers['content-type']);
                        // console.log('Content-length:',res.headers['content-length']);
                        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename).on('close',callback));

                    });
                }
                download(fullUrl,localPath,function(){console.log("Done")});
                var convertBufferdata=convertBuffer();
                      convertBufferdata.then(async function(result){
                                var image =await jpeg.decode(file_content, true)
                                const numChannels = 3
                                const numPixels = image.width * image.height
                                const values = new Int32Array(numPixels * numChannels)
                                for (let i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
                                    for (let c = 0; c < numChannels; ++c)
                                        values[i * numChannels + c] = image.data[i * 4 + c]
                                test_data=tf.tensor3d(values, [image.height, image.width, numChannels], 'int32')
                                var predictions=await _model.classify(test_data);
                                jsonObj[String(arrayAsins[i])]=predictions;
                                console.log('JsonObj',jsonObj);
                                i=i+1;
                                console.log("I going out is",i);
                                iterator(i);
                      },function(err){console.log(err)})
                })
            .catch(error=>{
                i=arrayCodes.length+1;
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
})

const load_model = async () => {
  _model = await nsfw.load()
}

load_model().then(() => app.listen(8080))
```

What problem I am facing is that the code is not completely synchronous due to which the resultant Json object is maybe having more keys than it should be or maybe not all the values retrieved are correct (meaning that it is getting overwritten).

*** After every time the single image gets fetched and processed , the next image is then download/overwritten to the same image ***

Any kind of help in refactoring of the code or making some changes to fix the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: The issue got resolve , while calling a async promise function the point of creating the Promise object gets nullified , so I removed it outside the object and called it after the promise object is returned . The issues got resolved.